# Release version crashing due to msvcp120d.dll

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, release

My code is crashing in the Release configuration but not the Debug configuration.  It's only doing this as I exit the program as the very last line 'return(0);' executes.  I'm working in the Visual Studio development environment and when it crashes, VS studio offers me the option to 'Debug' the code.  When I select that, it leads to an error dialog that pops up saying:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF851A0512D (msvcp120d.dll) in myapp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

When I select to 'break' when this exception occurs, it highlights the following function in the xstring file:

```
void _Free_proxy()
    {   // destroy proxy
    typename _Alloc::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
        _Alproxy;
    this->_Orphan_all();
    _Alproxy.destroy(this->_Myproxy);
    _Alproxy.deallocate(this->_Myproxy, 1);
    this->_Myproxy = 0;
    }
```

And, especially, the line '_Alproxy.destroy(this->_Myproxy);' is highlighted as the culprit.

I thought the issue might be that my 'release' code is somehow linking to the 'debug' msvcp120d.dll library since that's highlighted in the 1st dialog that pops up - but that may be just because I start using the VS debugger to ID this problem.  But even if that is the problem, I'm uncertain how to tell VS to compile with msvcp120.dll for the Release configuration and msvcp120d.dll for the Debug configuration.

(For the record, I'm generating all my code using the 'Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)' flag in the Release configuration and the 'Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)' in the Debug configuration)

The kicker is that when the Release version crashes, the process enters a 'suspended' state and I'm unable to fully kill it via task manager.  And then I can't even recompile a new Release version without restarting my computer!

I don't know how to isolate this problem.  Can anyone advise me on how I might fix this?

---

Update

The code for this project is quite large - so distilling it to a minimal version that exhibits the same behavior, while usually a valid way to track a bug, would be a pretty big task.  I was hoping that there was some method to log the processes and figure out which one is calling msvcp120d.dll @Niall, I generated the dependency graph and it is huge. Without giving away anything proprietary, attached is a global view of the graph.
[Dependency graph of entire solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4vq7.png)
Is there any tool to track which is calling msvcp120d.dll?

Comment: It sounds like you have undefined behavior in your code.  Can you make a [mcve] the exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: Either you or one of your dependencies links in msvcp120d.dll (the debug version of the runtime) into the release build. Mixing the runtimes can lead to issues like this. To track down who, you can use Dependency Walker to list the tree of dependencies.

Comment: msvcp120d.dll is part of the Visual Studio 2013 debug crt. If it is used in release I would expect  UB since Debug and Release runtimes are incompatible with each other. Make sure your application and all of your dependent dlls  are built in the same configuration. It is also not safe to mix compiler versions.

Comment: Your program is corrupting the heap.  Seeing msvcp120d.dll loaded in your process is practically a guarantee that this will happen.  Basic C++ template class objects like std::string do not have the same layout in the debug and the release build.  This is not Java or C# that runs with a VM to ensure everybody agrees what an object looks like.  In C++ you **must** build everything you link, including libraries that you did not build yourself, with the exact same compiler using the exact same settings.

Comment: I don't recognize that graph off hand, but this is the tool I was talking about. http://www.dependencywalker.com

Answer (score 2):

@Niall  Thank you! The software at Dependencywalker.com was fantastic.  I was able to use it to determine the library causing the problem and track down the error. It turns out that I had previously (months ago, dumbly) set a system path to the debug version of that library.  So even though my project was properly directed to link to the release version of the library, at runtime, my executable was linking to the debug version of the *.dll file!

I deleted the path variable and now make sure a copy of the proper *.dll file is in my Release or Debug directory. Then it all runs and shuts down fine.

Thanks to all who provided assistance.